# How to replace each indice of a substring

Tags: java, regex, replace

```
String s = "Elephant";
String srep = (s.replaceAll(s.substring(4,6), "_" ));

System.out.println(srep);
```

So my code outputs `Elep_nt` But I want it to replace each individual indice of that substring with an underscore so that it would output `Elep__nt`
is there anyway to do this in a single line? would I have to use a loop?

Comment: What benefit do you think doing it in a single line would have?

Answer (score 4):

The problem with yours is that you are matching `"ha"` at once, thus it gets replaced by only one char. (Notice also if you had `"Elephantha"` the last `"ha"` would be replaced as well.)

You could use a [lookbehind](http://www.regular-expressions.info/lookaround.html#lookbehind) to determine each single character to be replaced. So to **"replace chars from position *4 to 5*"**  you could use:

```
String s = "Elephant";
String srep = s.replaceAll("(?<=^.{4,5}).", "_");

System.out.println(srep);
```

Output:

```
Elep__nt
```

Answer (score 2):

You can use a `StringBuilder`:

```
StringBuilder result = new StringBuilder(s.length());

result.append(s.substring(0, 4));

for (int i = 4; i < 6; i++)
    result.append('_');

result.append(s.substring(6));

String srep = result.toString();
System.out.println(srep);
```

```
Elep__nt
```

Answer (score 1):

Since you have asked for oneliner here is another possible way.

```
String srep = s.substring(0,4)+s.substring(4,6).replaceAll(".", "_")+s.substring(6);
```

Or using `StringBuilder`

```
String srep = new StringBuilder(s).replace(4, 6, s.substring(4,6).replaceAll(".", "_")).toString();
```

Output

```
Elep__nt
```

But note that internally regex `replaceAll` uses loop anyways

Answer (score 0):

```
int difference = 6-4;

StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
for(int count=0; count<difference; count++){
    sb.append("_");
} 

String s = "Elephant";
  String srep = (s.replaceAll(s.substring(4,6), sbsb.toString() ));
```